What does sensitivity refer to in this study?
A study I'm reading is looking at some metrics (number of peaks per meter, etc.) to compare them on a young and elderly group of subjects.  It states 'Sensitivity and within-group variability were analyzed on the basis of z-scores (reference: distribution of elderly subjects). Sensitivity was expressed as the mean z-score and within-group variability was calculated by 1-std(z-scores)/mean(z-scores) (with =1 being perfectly stable and <0 being perfectly unstable). The z-standardization was performed in order to be able to compare the sensitivity between the different parameters.'
It also gives this table:

I don't understand what they mean by mean z-score - surely this is always 0?

Proving a proper reference would have been great but an exact citation from the article is the next best thing. Here it is: Gulde P, Hermsdörfer J. Smoothness Metrics in Complex Movement Tasks. Front Neurol. 2018 Sep 12;9:615. doi: 10.3389/fneur.2018.00615. Erratum in: Front Neurol. 2023 Sep 14;14:1279682. PMID: 30258393; PMCID: PMC6143727.

What does the $\text{std}(z\text{-scores})$ function do? Aren't $z\text{-scores}$ already standardized by definition?

As raised in the comments the source is here, although the question already contains most of what's needed to answer. To reproduce the full calculations Table 1 is also informative:

The key element is that z-scores were based on the elderly. So, you can take any statistic from the young cohort, get the cumulative density for that value in the respective elderly distribution, turn that into a standard normal quantile and there's your 'young' z-score. Note that these will not have $\mu=0$ or $\sigma=1$, you can reproduce Table 2 entirely from Table 1:
## Calculate a z score based on 'old' distribution
z <- function(x, old_mu, old_sigma) qnorm(pnorm(x, old_mu, old_sigma))

## Mean young peaks per meter z-score
z(-5.43, -7.82, 1.22)
#> 1.96

## Upper SD young peaks per meter z-score
z(-5.43 + 0.67, -7.82, 1.22)
#> 2.51      ## note that upper - mean = 0.55, the reported SD

## Peaks per meter within-group variability
1 - (2.51-1.96)/1.96
#> 0.72

Aside, this is just to explain how the calculations were done, I have never seen an approach like this before & can't comment on its appropriateness.
